# Oracle Invalid number ORA-01722: invalid number 01722. 00000 - "invalid number"

Tags: oracle

i am trying to multiply string value which is 33.000000 but i am getting error ORA-01722.

Can you please advise how to proper convert/cast this field in order to multiply?

select c1.name as Model,
p22.value as basisAMT,
p23.value  as TotalAMT

MODEL   BasisAMT    TotalAMT
Auto    0.000000    0.000000
Auto    22.000000   33.000000
Auto    0.000000    0.000000
Auto    0.000000    0.000000

But then i am trying to do

select c1.name as Model,
100 * p22.value as basisAMT,
p23.value  as TotalAMT

The error appears.

Comment: What you report, taken in isolation, is simply false. `select '33.00000000' * 3 from dual` does not throw an error; even better, it returns the correct answer, `99`. So, there are other things you didn't tell us. what you DID tell us is not enough.

Comment: Sorry, i did not mention that this value is comming from field VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)

Comment: That doesn't matter. What does matter is, how did you conclude that the problem came from the string '33.00000000'? How do you know it is not coming from another string, which can't be converted to number (also in the same column, but a different row)?

Comment: I have updated description, i hope its clear.

Comment: No, it is not clear. How did you decide that the error was thrown by the '33.00000000' string, and not something else? Hint: you may have a value in the **p22** column that can NOT be converted to number. For example, something like '33. 000000' (with a space after the decimal point). So - how did you decide that the offending string was the one you mentioned, and not a different one?

Comment: i have tried to execute select '33.00000000' * 3 from dual and received an error 
ORA-01722: invalid number
01722. 00000 -  "invalid number"
*Cause:    The specified number was invalid.
*Action:   Specify a valid number.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228051/discussion-between-mathguy-and-luckyday).

Comment: **CONCLUSION** After continuing the discussion with the OP in private chat, we figured out that his decimal "point" is comma. The proper solution is to enclose the string column within TO_NUMBER and to give explicit NLS numeric characters, like this: `to_number(p22.value, '9999d99999999', 'nls_numeric_characters=.,')`

Answer (score 0):

can you debug code that you cannot see?  No? So why do you expect that of others?

It is illogical to do math on a character string.  The fact that the characters in the string are all numeric doesn't change the fact that computers treat them as characters, no different than

```
'my name is fred' * 23
```

And we don't even know that all the characters are numeric.  It could be padded with space characters.

You need to look at the [TO_NUMBER()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sqlrf/TO_NUMBER.html#GUID-D4807212-AFD7-48A7-9AED-BEC3E8809866) function.

Comment: Oracle is pretty good (or "pretty bad" in my opinion, as you know) at converting between data types. If the string is in fact numeric, Oracle will convert it to number, even if we don't call TO_NUMBER explicitly. And it is able to trim whitespace (not only spaces, but also tabs!) on both sides of the number. It wouldn't trim a space right after the decimal point, for example - but the OP's string doesn't have a space after the decimal point. There is something else that the OP didn't tell us.

Comment: @mathguy - all true.  I don't believe in relying on implicit conversions.  I hoped that pointing the OP to the correct explicit function would help re-enforce the basic point that strings are not numbers.